# WinForms : Can't open Designer for one form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I Was working on a project and I couldn't **open** the designer for one of my **Forms**. But I **could** open it before. Now its icon changed to the **class icon** and I don't know what happened.

[image: In Solution Explorer (Pos.cs ->)]

[image: Full Window]

**Used References**

```
using PosAB_2023.Scripts;
using PosAB_2023.UserControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

That was my main form I worked in for a while and has the most work. Do I have to remake the form or this can be fixed somehow?

Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Fixed, Problem was that I had another class in the same level in same file.
I removed it and its working again.